# Как в 1с битрикс при xml импорте hl-block через админку, прописать правило заполнения поля?

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в битриксе задать правило, чтобы при импорте хайлоад блока через админку значение одного из полей рассчитывалось по формуле:

```
'поле3' = md5(serialize(['поле1','поле2']));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение называется обработчики событий для highload блоков

Нужно повесить обработчик OnBeforeAdd в файле init.php

```
$eventManager = \Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance();
$eventManager->addEventHandler('', 'ColorsOnBeforeAdd', 'OnBeforeAdd');

/**
*
* @param \Bitrix\Main\Entity\Event $event
* @return \Bitrix\Main\Entity\EventResult
*/
function OnBeforeAdd(\Bitrix\Main\Entity\Event $event) {
$entity = $event->getEntity();
$entityDataClass = $entity->GetDataClass();
// тип события. вернет ColorsOnBeforeAdd
$eventType = $event->getEventType();
// получаем массив полей хайлоад блока
$arFields = $event->getParameter("fields");
//получить все доступные в этом событие данные
$arParameters = $event->getParameters();

$result = new \Bitrix\Main\Entity\EventResult();

//модификация данных
if (empty($arFields['POLE1'])) {
    $arFields['POLE3'] = 
md5(serialize([$arFields['POLE1'],$arFields['POLE2']]));  
    $result->modifyFields($arFields);
}

return $result;
}
```

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2244&LESSON_PATH=3913.5062.5748.2244#events